# Syntax for new class declarations in PHP

Tags: php, syntax, warnings, error-reporting, maintainability

I inherited a php project that was previously assigned to another development company and I often see very strange code implementations which I've never seen before and which I think are probably errors. That said, they are everywhere and the server logs don't complain about them or cast warnings. It's possible that `error_reporting` has been turned off somewhere.

For example, I am seeing a lot of class declarations like this:

```
$registration = new EventRegistration;
```

That's strange to me, as I've only ever seen class instancing using `new` done as:

```
$registration = new EventRegistration();
```

Can someone clarify if this is incorrect / not best practice / passable?

I assume it's just a syntax error that will compile but is technically wrong. Something similar to when people do array syntax like `$array[key]` instead of `$array['key']`. Is that correct?

Thanks.

Comment: No it isn't an error or warning or technically wrong, braces are only necessary if there are any arguments that need passing to the class constructor

Comment: Okay thanks, I do see why it wouldn't be needed without any constructor args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `new` keyword you want to create a new object, if that object does not require any arguments (as defined in the `__construct()` method) its perfectly fine do leave out the `()`.

```
class foo{
    function __construct(){}
} // valid

class bar{
    function __construct($arg = null){}
} // valid

class foobar{
    function __construct($arg){}
} // not valid
```

In this scenario, only `foobar` will trigger a warning if you do not pass any args. Its a matter of preference I would say.

But for `$array[key]` would say `key` is a constant and would likely trigger a warning.

Comment: Yes that's true although `$array[key]` will compile it does cast a warning with error reporting turned on. It's not good syntax but I've seen it elsewhere in the project. Thanks for the constructor examples, I understand what's up now.

Comment: Because PHP can assume (read the warning), doesn't mean its right.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's incorrect though passes that's why I wanted to check on the class declarations also. There's a lot that needs to be changed in this project xD